# SharePoint WebPart won't update without IISRESET when deployed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, visual-studio, iis

I'm using visual studio 2017 to create a Visual WebPart for SharePoint 2013 and I have deployed it using visual studio but the problem is that the webpart won't update without resseting iis. How can I deploy the solution and seeing changes without the need of iisreset.

Due to this problem I am also having issues with debugging, it wont hit the break point.

Answer (score 2):

Deploying a solution always resets the IIS that is the way it SP works. In order to debug it  from the VS you need t attach debuger to correct w3wp.exe process (as your dll will be loaded after you reset IIS) Here are some steps for remote debugging http://sharepointdecode.blogspot.com/2017/02/remote-debugging-sharepoint-2013-farm.html

It is easier if you have dev machine with VS installed there is less steps to set it up.

Comment: but why the visual studio wont reset iis by its own?

Comment: It can you just need to tell it to do it. I am not developing these days much outside powershell, but for SP projects i remember I was setting up post build actions (to reset iis or timer service if I was developing timer features) have a look at this article it mentions the post build events. https://bamboosolutions.com/2009/03/10-best-practices/